# mysql_query executes only once when looping - php

Tags: mysql

I have some code that will automatically assign a certain number of plates when entered in the field `$num_plates`. However, when looping the `mysql_query` only works once:

```
$region = $_POST['region'];
$num_plates = $_POST['num_plates']; //4

$prfx = 'AAA';
$sffx = '1001';
$c = 1;

while($c <= $num_plates) 
{
    $prfx = ++$prfx;
    $sffx = ++$sffx;

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO v_info (`plate_prefix`, `plate_suffix`, `region`, `status`) 
                 VALUES ('$prfx', '$sffx', '$region', 'Available')");

    $c = $c+1;
    echo "<h1 align='center'>".$c."</h1>";
}
```

Comment: your first problem, you are using mysql_, [don't use mysql_*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12860046/1028804)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple queries are explicitly not supported by `mysql_query`. From [the manual](http://php.net/mysql-query):

> mysql_query() sends a unique query (multiple queries are not
>   supported) to the currently active database on the server that's
>   associated with the specified link_identifier.

On the other hand, [mysqli does support multiple queries](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php). You need to use that.